# Convert string to decimal but keep numeric portion

Tags: c#, string, decimal

Is there a way to convert a string to decimal in C# but ignoring trailing "garbage"? i.e. like PHP's `floatval()` or C `strtod()` ?

e.g. 
Convert string `"2974.23abcdefs"` to decimal `2974.23`

Comment: There are many resources on the web if you try to search for it

Comment: @ZoomVirus No, there aren't for floating points... and it's a complex problem. For integers it is much easier.

Comment: Do you want to support scientific notation? Which culture do you want to use? Do you want to allow thousands separators? In the simplest case (invariant culture, no scientific notation) a regex like `^[+-]?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]*)?` should work to extract the number.

Comment: You cant convert but easily you can extract the Number from this string

Comment: Why do you want to do this? I can't think of a situation where this would be useful.

Comment: @CodesInChaos C does it... Do you want to tell to Mr. K&R that it was a stupid idea? :)

Comment: @CodesInChaos users, man!

Comment: @CodesInChaos I have to tell the truth, once or twice (but no more than twice), I missed an `int.Parse `(or perhaps it was a `double.Parse`, don't remember) with the C syntax. I'm saving the answer I'm giving somewhere. Perhaps I'll need it a third time :)

Comment: @xanatos The C variant has its uses, since it returns a pointer to end of the number, so it can be used to build a parser with sane rules. Simply ignoring garbage suffixes on the other hand is rarely a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, there is no exact, like for like, replacement for what you can do in PHP and I think, for good reason. In the scenario of a web application, I'm not really sure that if I were accepting a decimal with garbage at the end, I'd actually want to consider that as valid data but this is just my opinion.

What you can do is define a regular expression that would capture the decimal and recognise that this is happening. I find this much safer and reliable.

Obviously, **the regular expression can be improved** but this is a simple example for you: -

```
var match = Regex.Match("2974.23abcdefs", "^([0-9]+\\.[0-9]+)(.+)?$");
if (match.Success)
{
    // See the also the link below for using Decimal.TryParse
    Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToDecimal(match.Groups[1].Value));
}
```

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx for my preferred way to convert to a decimal. This would ensure that you are coping with the output of the regular expression for how Decimal is comprised

For more information on regular expressions, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

As a <strike>first</strike>, <strike>second</strike>, third try, this should go:

```
static double Parse(string str, IFormatProvider provider = null)
{
    if (str == string.Empty)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    if (provider == null)
    {
        provider = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
    }

    NumberFormatInfo nfi = NumberFormatInfo.GetInstance(provider);

    // [ws][sign][integral-digits[,]]integral-digits[.[fractional-digits]][E[sign]exponential-digits][ws]
    string ws = @"\s*";
    string sign = @"(" + Regex.Escape(nfi.PositiveSign) + "|" + Regex.Escape(nfi.NegativeSign) + ")?";
    string integralDigits1 = "([0-9](" + Regex.Escape(nfi.NumberGroupSeparator) + ")*)*";
    string integralDigits2 = "[0-9]+";
    string fractionalDigits = "(" + Regex.Escape(nfi.NumberDecimalSeparator) + "[0-9]*)?";
    string exponentialDigits = "([Ee]" + sign + "[0-9]+)?";

    var rx = new Regex(ws + sign + integralDigits1 + integralDigits2 + fractionalDigits + exponentialDigits);

    string match = rx.Match(str).ToString();

    if (match == string.Empty)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    return double.Parse(match, provider);
}
```

Note that the composed regex is very complex, because there are various "parts" in a full double that has been written to a string.

From MSDN:

> [ws][sign][integral-digits[,]]integral-digits[.[fractional-digits]][E[sign]exponential-digits][ws]

Still some numbers will crash this function, if they are too much big. So passing `new string('9', 1000)` will make the `double.Parse` throw an exception.

Use it like:

```
double num = Parse("        +1,0.1234E+12abcdefgh", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

or

```
double num = Parse("        +1,,,,,0.1234E+12abcdefgh");
```

(if you don't need to configure the culture, will use the `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`)

Answer (score 0):

This works but  only takes care of digits and the current culture's decimal-separator:

```
string input = "2974.23abcdefs";
decimal d;
char decSep = NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.NumberDecimalSeparator[0]; // there is no culture with a decimal-separator that has more than one letter so this isn't harmful
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(input) && Char.IsDigit(input[0]))
{
    string number = string.Concat(input.TakeWhile(c => Char.IsDigit(c) || decSep == c));
    bool validDecimal = decimal.TryParse(number, out d);
    Console.WriteLine("Valid? {0} Parsed to: {1}", validDecimal, d);
}
```

Since we are using `,` as decimal separator here in germany i get a different result than people who use `.` as separator. You get `2974.23` and i get `2974`.

Comment: Interesting use for TakeWhile!

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do so. I suggest using a Regex first, and then `decimal.TryParse()`.

This is a regex that grabs a floating point number at the begin of the string, like -123.43 or just 1234.56 or 123456:

```
^([+-][0-9]+\.?[0-9]*).*$
```

Putting this into C# looks like this:

```
    // Step 1: Getting some input
    String input = "123.4533wefwe";

    // Step 2: Get rid of the trail 
    Regex r = new Regex(@"^([+-][0-9]+\.?[0-9]*).*$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    MatchCollection matches = r.Matches(input);
    if (matches.Count > 0) {
        Match match = matches[0];
        GroupCollection groups = match.Groups;

        // Step 3: create a real decimal from the string
        decimal i;
        NumberStyles style;
        CultureInfo culture;
        style = NumberStyles.Number;
        culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB");

        String matchedNumber = groups[1].Value;

        if (decimal.TryParse(matchedNumber, style, culture, out i)) {

           // Step 4: giving back the result: 
           Console.WriteLine("Parsed decimal: " + i);
        }            
    }
```

The output of this is:

```
Parsed decimal: 123.4533
```

**Remark:** All this seems to become a bigger problem if you would like to parse real floating point number literals that include exponential notation. Then, severals stages of casting would be necessary.

Comment: nitpick, your writeline statement is not actually a floating point type, there's still the task of converting that string to a decimal/double/float

Comment: That's not nitpick. That's not reading the OP's question to the end :-/ Thx. Of course there should be a second part... I'm on it...